# How to change Sound device without visiting System Preferences?

Tags: macos, audio, preferences

Are there any alternative ways to switch your Input/Output sound device in OS X?  My goal is to avoid going through System Preferences and have as few keystrokes/steps as possible.

Comment: What does "easy" mean? Keyboard shortcut, Terminal command/script, Keyboard Maestro macro, or something else?

Comment: Well, easy means achieved without great effort; presenting few difficulties. Easy for each person is different . I just discovered this and thought of sharing with the community as I had to do lot of searching to find this one out. Might help people like me, who find 2 clicks quick and easy than several clicks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: alt/option click on Sound icon on top menu.]

To enable the sound icon on the top menu bar, only once you have to go to System Preferences-> Sound-> Show volume in menu bar

alt/option + click on the Sound icon on the menu bar to get this dropdown and select the desired output or input device

Comment: There's also a method by Applescript - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/218223/85275