# Automatically use USB sound card when plugged in?

Tags: macos, audio, usb

I have an [external sound card](http://www.fiio.net/en/products/44) that I plug into my computer through USB.

Is there any way I can tell OS X to always default to it as output when it's available? Even if I plug it in while the computer is already on?

I use OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: I doubt it. I've never had an external audio interface that would even be recognised unless it was present at boot.

Comment: @Tetsujin Mine is recognized even if I plug it in later. But I have to manually select it as output device.

Comment: I wonder if the script I did for this might help - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/218223/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin This looks cool. How is it to be used? What should trigger the script?

Comment: I'm not good enough with the underlying mechanism to be able to fully automate it, sorry. Key command would be my solution, unless someone else is able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Tetsujin Key command sounds pretty handy :) So I just add it as a Service and assign it to a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Yup, better than digging in the prefs... not as good as full auto, but best I can do.