# Is it possible to make a hotkey for switching audio output?

Tags: keyboard, macos, display, audio

I am using external monitors. Because of this, whenever my mac goes to sleep, it automatically redirects output to the monitor. This is annoying to fix, as I have to move my mouse and click to fix it every time. Is there a way to set a hotkey to toggle the sound output for me? something like `command+shift+s`

[image]

Comment: See my answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217148/using-apple-script-to-manage-sound-output-selection/218223#218223 - you could use this in Automator, saved as a Service.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. I am having trouble implementing that for my problem. I am new to applescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you only have the two output devices, the following *code* will toggle between the two.

```
tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Sound"
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        tell tab group 1 of window "Sound"
            if (selected of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1) then
                set selected of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
            else
                set selected of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

I test this as an Automator Service using a Run AppleScript *action* and then assigned it a hot-key combo and it works on my system having only two sound outputs.  The tricky part is going to be finding a hot-key combo that isn't assigned to any or all apps already.

As an example <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> is Save As... in Safari, but if the Desktop has focus when pressed it works to trigger the Service.

1. Open Automator.
2. File > New > Service, with setting as shown in the image.
3. Add a Run AppleScript *action* an replace the default *code* with the *code* Above.
4. Save the Service as, e.g.: Toggle Sound Device
5. Assign it a keyboard shortcut in: System Preferences > Keyboard >  Shortcuts > Services

[image: Toggle Sound Device]

Comment: @kilojoules, See updated answer.

Comment: @kilojoules, Thanks for accepting the answer. BTW I've updated the **AppleScript** _code_ to a better version to do the same thing only now you don't have to see the **System Preferences** window show and it opens directly to the target _tab_ of the target _pane_ and introduces _error handling_ so the switch can be made when the _objects_ are available. I'd use the updated _code_ over my original _code_.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great solution if you only have two audio output options.  Unfortunately, my mac is counting my monitors as outputs and placing them as #1 & #2.  Nonetheless,  thanks for sharing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).