# set the default audio output device in macOS

Tags: audio

Is there a way to set the default audio output source in macOS. Or even better be able to set a hierarchical preference list, as to which audio output device you would prefer in a similar way to how you can with network connections in the network preference tabs?

Comment: I don't think there is. I wrote this solution based on an earlier script to hot-key outputs, but it's dependant on position in a list rather than specific output - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/218223/85275

Comment: I'd love Hierarchical out put preference! When I dock, I have 3 sound devices that get connected (Monitor, Thunderbolt dock, High Quality DAC), and MacOS chooses the worst one; the monitor.