# Can I make certain menus always show ⌥option + click results?

Tags: audio, menu-bar

Specifically in reference to the Volume menu item in the menu bar;

As I am frequently changing audio input/output settings, and never using the slider that the normal volume menu click shows (I always only use the keyboard incremental volume keys for a few reasons), I'd like to make the volume menu more useful to me by automatically **always showing** the menu that appears when you ⌥option + click it.

And for obvious reasons I don't just want every system-wide click to be rebound to ⌥option + click, just the menu bar items if possible.

This sounds like a too-specific problem to have a solution, but thanks in advance if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do exactly that, but if you can't be bothered to use the option key when clicking (maybe you're holding an instrument with the other hand or something?) then a keyboard shortcut to an AppleScript to change audio devices is probably even better.

[Here's another question that addresses this approach](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/217148/656), and if it's not quite what you're looking for, [there are plenty of other people out there talking about this as well](https://www.google.com/search?q=applescript%20shortcut%20audio%20input).

Comment: Wow, this is the perfect response. I realised I failed to list why the function would be useful to me, but then you guessed it! I do in fact play guitar and when plugging in to GarageBand, I have to lean to the right so I use my left hand to hold the guitar from falling forward. Thanks for the links! I actually thought I was alone searching for about 10 minutes on Google, turns out the problem was different enough to not show up but it's an even better solution to my problem. Thanks!