# Quickly switch sound output from HDMI to Headphone jack OS X 10.10.5

Tags: macos, audio, hdmi, headphones

## How do you quickly change the output from the HDMI to aux/headphone jack in OS X 10.10.5?

Currently I change it this way.

**System Preferences -> Sound -> Output**

In windows it default switches to the aux/headphone jack when you plug in headphones.

Is there a way to accomplish this in OS X 10.10.5?

## Without Apple Script.

Comment: You could do it by Applescript - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217148/using-apple-script-to-manage-sound-output-selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable the "Show volume in menu bar" option from System Preferences -> Sound, you can quickly change default input/output devices by holding `alt` and clicking the volume icon in the menu bar.

(Note: I'm no sure in which version this was introduced, but I think it's already in 10.10.5)

Comment: Yup, it's in 10.10.5 Alt click saved the day. You've really helped improve my productivity!